# How to join Two table In Orcale Both matched or not matched

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables with some values. I want to join these tables. I need both which is matched and which is not matched. matched are in one row . not matched are in a single row. In my Table A want to join Based On CITY,
I Have attached Table example on Picture. and what I exactly want that is in my picture as Out put

```
SELECT * FROM TEST1 A,  TEST2 B WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=CUSER_ID(+)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM TEST1 A,  TEST2 B WHERE CUSER_ID=CUSTOMER_ID(+)
```

[output example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5kjY.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can do a full join. Use `coalesce()` on the city to get the non null city in case of non matching rows.

```
SELECT t1.customer_id,
       t1.customer_name,
       coalesce(t1.city, t2.city) city
       t2.user_id,
       t2.user_name
       FROM test1 t1
            FULL JOIN test2 t2
                      ON t2.city = t1.city;
```

And next time please don't post images of tables. Use DDL and DML or at least tabular text.

Answer (score 0):

To give you EXACTLY the output you specified... the following should give it to you.  The columns you want are listed and on the second SELECT the cuser_id is used instead of customer_id.

```
SELECT a.customer_id, a.customer_name, a.city, b.user_name FROM TEST1 A,  TEST2 B WHERE CUSTOMER_ID=CUSER_ID(+)
UNION 
SELECT b.cuser_id customer_id, a.customer_name, a.city, b.user_name FROM TEST1 A,  TEST2 B WHERE CUSER_ID=CUSTOMER_ID(+)
```